# Different Interpolation Types for Different Bones

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, interpolation

Im not sure if this question was asked before, but

Is there a way to define the interpolation type for specific bones? For Example, i want to switch the expression of a character in a snappy way, but use smooth body movements.

So for the **Expression Bones** i would use **Constant Interpolation** only and for the **Body Movement** i would use **Bezier Interpolation**.

The only way i know is to set a keyframe first and then change the interpolation on the keyframe by hand. It has worked out well for me so far, but wouldn't be it easier, if the interpolation would be setup in the rig already?